# How to Get All Record (Looping)

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Data :**
 Request Number : RO-001
Purchase Number: PO-16-001
Qty : 5
Item : Pencil
Price : 1.00
Total : 5.00
Purchase Number: PO-16-002
Qty : 2
Item : A4 Paper 
Price : 4.00
Total : 8.00
Qty : 3
Item : Book
Price : 15.00
Total :45.00
 **Output Now :**
  RO-001 |  PO-16-001 | 5 | Pencil | 1.00 | 5.00 
RO-001 |  PO-16-002 |  3 | Book | 15.00 | 45.00 
 **Why I can't reach this record ?** 
  RO-001 |  PO-16-002 | 2 | A4 Paper | 4.00 | 8.00

```
        $total_amount ='';
    foreach ($rows AS $row) {
        if ($row['id_supplier'] == $id_supplier)
         {
$qtys = $row['qtys'];
$unit_rm = $row['unit_rm'];
$total = $row['total'];
$total_amount += $total;          
 echo '<em>'. htmlentities($qtys, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').'</em><br>&nbsp;';
        echo '<em>'. htmlentities($unit_rm, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').'</em><br>&nbsp;';
        echo '<em>'. htmlentities($total, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').'</em><br>&nbsp;';}}

  foreach ($name_items AS $name_item) {

    echo $name_item;
     echo '<em>'. htmlentities($name_item, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').'</em><br>&nbsp;';
  }
echo '<em>'. htmlentities($inc_number, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').'</em><br>&nbsp;';
 echo '<em>'.htmlentities($cur_yr, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').'</em><br>&nbsp;';
     echo '<em>'. htmlentities($total_amount, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').'</em><br>&nbsp;';
 echo '<em>'. htmlentities($name_employee, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').'</em><br>&nbsp;';
 echo '<em>'. htmlentities($autoid, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').'</em><br>&nbsp;';?>  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="hidden" id="inc_number" name="inc_number[]" value="<?php echo $inc_number;?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" id="autoid" name="autoid[]" value="<?php echo $autoid;?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" id="year"  name="year[]" value="<?php echo $cur_yr;?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" id="name_employee" name="name_employee[]" value="<?php echo $name_employee;?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" id="status_po" name="status_po[]"/>
      <input type="hidden" id="date" name="date[]"/>
      <input type="hidden" id="id_submit" name="id_submit[]"/>
      <input type="hidden" id="id_supplier" name="id_supplier[]" value="<?php echo $id_supplier; ?>"/>
 <input type="hidden" id="name_item" name="name_item[]" value="<?php echo $name_item; ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="request_number" name="request_number" value="<?php echo $request_number;?>"/>

 <input type="hidden" id="unit_rm" name="unit_rm[]" value="<?php echo $unit_rm; ?>"/>

 <input type="hidden" name="qty[]" id="qty" value="<?php echo $qtys; ?>" class="form-control input-sm">

 <input type="hidden" name="total_amount[]" id="total_amount" value="<?php echo $total_amount; ?>" class="form-control input-sm">

<input type="hidden" name="amount[]" id="amount" value="<?php echo $total; ?>" class="form-control input-sm">
  </div><?php}  } }?>     <input type="submit" name="submit_autoid" id="submit_autoid" value="Submit Order" 
  class="btn pull-right btn success"/></a> 
   </form>       
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_autoid'])){
$request_number=$_POST['request_number'];
$inc_number=$_POST['inc_number'];
$autoid=$_POST['autoid'];
$name_item=$_POST['name_item'];
$year=$_POST['year'];
$name_employee=$_POST['name_employee'];
$status_po=$_POST['status_po'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$id_supplier=$_POST['id_supplier'];
$qtys=$_POST['qty'];
$unit_rm=$_POST['unit_rm'];
$total=$_POST['amount'];
$total_amount=$_POST['total_amount'];
$id_submit=$_POST['id_submit'];   
for($i=0; $i<count($inc_number); $i++){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_autoid (request_number,inc_number,autoid,year,name_employee,status_po, date, id_supplier, total_amount, id_submit)
    VALUES ('$request_number', '".$inc_number[$i]."', '".$autoid[$i]."','".$year[$i]."','".$name_employee[$i]."','In Process',now(), '".$id_supplier[$i]."','".$total_amount[$i]."', '1')") or die('Error'); }

         for($m=0; $m<count($name_item); $m++){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_purchase_order (autoid,request_number,id_supplier,name_item,qty,unit_rm,amount, status, date, name_employee)
    VALUES ('".$autoid[$m]."','$request_number', '".$id_supplier[$m]."', '".$name_item[$m]."','".$qtys[$m]."','".$unit_rm[$m]."','".$total[$m]."','Done', NOW(),'".$name_employee[$m]."')") or die('Error'); }
  ?>
<script>
window.location="record.php?request_number=<?php echo $request_number; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: do you want to retrieve a record ?

Comment: yes..supposed to be I get 3 record

Comment: can you provide your query sql? Without it, we cannot know what you really do. And please also make sure A4 paper belongs to RO-001 in your DB.

Comment: Because `$i = 0;` & your rows start at the id of `1`. Change it to `$i = 1;`.

Comment: Thanks @Darren but it not true answer..when I changed $i = 1; I just get this record only RO-001 | PO-16-002 | 2 | A4 Paper | 4.00 | 8.00

Comment: make condition $i<=count($inc_number);

Comment: @KamleshGupta same with Darren..I only get this record RO-001 | PO-16-002 | 2 | A4 Paper | 4.00 | 8.00

Comment: can i see your all code?

Comment: Why don't you use `foreach()` instead of `for` then?

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: @miss please edit your code into your question if it is only an addendum and doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I already try put foreach () at for but not work..this is structure I try..it is true?  foreach ($name_items AS $name_item){  for($m=0; $m<count($name_item); $m++){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_purchase_order (autoid,request_number,id_supplier,name_item,qty,unit_rm,amount, status, date, name_employee)
    VALUES ('".$autoid[$m]."','$request_number', '".$id_supplier[$m]."', '".$name_item[$m]."','".$qtys[$m]."','".$unit_rm[$m]."','".$total[$m]."','Done', NOW(),'".$name_employee[$m]."')") or die('Error'); } }  .. @Darren

Comment: @KamleshGupta my code at above

Comment: @melson.jao my code at above

Comment: Still not show the sql about how you query your list, ex select * from ..... I guess PO-16-002 has 2 items A4 paper and book. And somehow in your query sql, only book is selected. Maybe you use group by or distinct or wrong join ... Anyway, none can help if information is not enough. for or foreach or html layout code is not the point. You should try to print_r($rows) to see what really inside and let us know how you get rows.

Comment: BTW, the PHP and html mixed code is really a bad coding style. Try to use some general template framework will make you easy and happy coding.

Comment: @melson.jao.. here sql statement.. data is output I get when I compile it..thank you for your suggestion..i'm still new in coding world

Comment: You use tbl_category_item as main search table and left join tbl_reqorder_uv, ,tbl_supplier, ,tbl_item_list. It means if item category cannot found in tbl_category_item, it won't be selected even if it in id_item_list. I guess the category of A4 paper is NULL or it is not existed in tbl_category_item. In your case, you should select from tbl_category_item or tbl_reqorder_uv and left join the rest table like category or supplier.

Comment: EX, select tbl_reqorder_uv.*, tbl_item_list.name_item, tbl_category_item.category, tbl_supplier.name_company
FROM tbl_reqorder_uv 
LEFT JOIN tbl_item_list ON tbl_reqorder_uv.id_item_list = tbl_item_list.id_item_list,
LEFT JOIN tbl_supplier ON tbl_reqorder_uv.id_supplier = tbl_supplier.id_supplier,
LEFT JOIN tbl_item_list ON tbl_reqorder_uv.id_category = tbl_category_item.id_category,
WHERE tbl_reqorder_uv.request_number ='$request_number' ORDER BY tbl_reqorder_uv.request_number, tbl_reqorder_uv.id_supplier, tbl_reqorder_uv.id_item_list

Comment: If you have any problem, before checking the PHP output part, you should dump PHP array first and check the sql result from DB side first to make sure the problem is not caused by improper SQL.